# Rendering a partial inside a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render the following partial:

```
<% @accepted.each do |question| %>
  <div class="questions-container__content">
    <div class="questions-container__accepted-content">                 
      ...
    </div>  
    <%= render 'question_buttons', collection: @accepted %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with `_question_buttons.html.erb`:

```
<div class="links-container__button-group" id="link-buttons">
  <%= link_to "View submission", coin_question_path(question.coin, question.id), class: "primary-small","data-turbolinks"=>"false" %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_coin_question_path(question.coin, question.id), class: "primary-small","data-turbolinks"=>"false" %>
  <% if !question.accepted? %>
    <%= link_to "Activate" , activate_coin_question_path(question.coin, question.id), class: "primary-small","data-turbolinks"=>"false" %>
  <% else %> 
    <%= link_to "Deactivate" , deactivate_coin_question_path(question.coin, question.id), class: "primary-small","data-turbolinks"=>"false" %>
  <% end %> 
  <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to (question.rejected ? "Restore" : "Reject"), reject_coin_question_path(question.coin, question.id), class: "primary-small","data-turbolinks"=>"false" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `question' for #<#<Class:0x00007fece6998d08>:0x00007fed02072bb8>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you need to pass the `question` variable from `each` loop in the parent view through to the partial using `locals` which allows the partial to access it.

```
    <%= render 'question_buttons', locals: { question: question } %>
```

Comment: does this work on your version of rails? `<%= render 'question_buttons', question: question %>`?

Comment: i don't see the use of `collection` variable either. why do you have it there?

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

When rendering a collection, each item of the collection is passed to the partial as a local variable with the same name as partial itself. It means that for this call:

```
<%= render 'question_buttons', collection: @accepted %>
```

the partial `question_buttons` will be called for each item of `@accepted` array; that item will be available inside partial as `question_buttons`.

If you want to use another name for the item, for example `question`, you need to call it as:

```
<%= render 'question_buttons', collection: @accepted, as: :question %>
```

Another option -- just rename the partial to `question`:

```
<%= render 'question', collection: @accepted %>
```

---

**Second:**

In your code snippet rendering collection is called on each iteration of the loop over `@accepted` elements. If `@accepted` has 8 elements, for example, the partial will be rendered 8 times for each of these elements, ie 8 * 8 = 64 times in total.  I suspect that it's not what you want to achieve. Your code looks like `question_buttons` partial needs to be rendered for each element of `@accepted` only once. In this case using `collection` param has no sense here. Just pass a local variable `question` into the partial:

```
<%= render 'question_buttons', question: question %>
```